# How can I bundle a font with my .net winforms application?

Tags: .net, winforms, fonts

I'd like to use a non-standard font for my .net 3.0 Winforms application.

This font might be installed on some of my user's computer, but it will clearly be missing on some others.

How can I ship the font with my program ? Do I need to install the font ? If so, is the lack of administrator privileges going to be an issue?

Comment: How is your program "shipped"? Zip file? Installer? Both?

Comment: We support both methods, depending on what the client prefers. That being said, we can easily execute the font registration code directly at client start-up (provided of course it doesn't need administrative privileges)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use an installer to get the font registered on the target machine.  But maybe you won't have to, GDI+ supports [private fonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y505zzfw.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a blog article I wrote that shows a way to embed fonts as resources in your application (no dll imports necessary :).

[Embedding Fonts in your .Net Application](http://redwerb.com/post/Embedding-Fonts-in-your-Net-Application.aspx)

Here's the class I create where all the magic happens. The blog article includes instructions and an example of using it.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace EmbeddedFontsExample.Fonts
{
    public class ResFonts
    {
        private static PrivateFontCollection sFonts;
        static ResFonts()
        {
            sFonts = new PrivateFontCollection();
            // The order the fonts are added to the collection 
            // should be the same as the order they are added
            // to the ResFontFamily enum.
            AddFont(MyFonts.Consolas);
        }
        private static void AddFont(byte[] font)
        {
            var buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(font.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(font, 0, buffer, font.Length);
            sFonts.AddMemoryFont(buffer, font.Length);
        }
        public static Font Create(
            ResFontFamily family, 
            float emSize, 
            FontStyle style = FontStyle.Regular, 
            GraphicsUnit unit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        {
            var fam = sFonts.Families[(int)family];
            return new Font(fam, emSize, style, unit);
        }
    }
    public enum ResFontFamily
    {
        /// <summary>Consolas</summary>
        Consolas = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you've added the fonts as resources normally, the only thing I'd change is `AddFont(MyFonts.Consolas)` should be `AddFont(Resources.Consolas)`

Comment: The link is dead!

Comment: Sure is :). It's in BizArk now. The class is called FontUtil and here is the wiki page for it: https://github.com/BizArk/BizArk3/wiki/BizArk.Core.Util.FontUtil Note, v3 is still in beta, but seems to be fairly stable.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.matevarga.com/embedding-fonts-into-windows-forms/) explains in detail how to embed a font into a winforms project.

Comment: The link is dead