# Best Barcode Symbology for my Application

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode, fax

//Please don't close this post due to subjective reasons.
I'm developing a form-filling winform application which generates a PDF file on submitting the information. The PDF file need to contain barcodes encoding some information entered by user. The user prints the PDF file and put signature on it and faxes it back to us. I need suggestions for choosing which barcode symbology to use for this applcation.
The barcode needs to satisfy the following conditions.

```
  1)The barcode need to encode upto 120 characters
```

Since the barcode need to encode a lot of information, I think 2D Barcode would be better as it can store with much high information density.

```
  2)Only upper case alphabets and numbers need to be encoded
```

Though most of the 2D barcodes can store more than numbers, there are some 1D barcodes such as code 39 that cannot represent all alphabets.

```
  3)Preferable size of barcode is 1.5 inch height and 8 inch width
```

This is what is the most challenging requirement. I'm planning to place the barcode below the information such as account id. So it would be good if barcode takes the shape of a rectangle whose information capacity increases with its width. This requirement is suitable for 1D barcodes. Also, since 2D barcodes takes the shape of a square, a lot of space will be wasted on either side of barcode.

```
  4)Error correcting capability
```

2D barcodes have better error correcting capability. Only some 1D barcodes have error correction with it. This is not an essential requirement.

```
  5)The barcode need to be faxed from one country to another
```

The barcode is generated on a PDF. The PDF will be printed and then need to be faxed. So, the barcode needs to have high resolution. Otherwise, I fear that the scanner cannot decode data correctly. I'm thinking a resoltion of 200dpi is enough for the barcode image. Is there any problem to fax 2D barcodes as they need to be scanned both horizontally and verically. I have heard like fax have different resolution vertically and horizontally. Does this create any problem when scanning barcodes.

```
  6)Easiness to program in c# to generate barcode
```

Atlast but not the least, I need to program this barcode generation myselfin c#. So, there should be some free library available for the same. Aspose barcode is a good one. But it is costly.

I have come across the following Barcodes. I have checked the specification of some of these types. But couldn't reach a final decision. I can't turn back once I choose a barcode and start programming.

1D: UPC/EAN/JAN, Code 39, Code 128, Interleaved 2 of 5, Codabar, Code 11, Code 93, NEC 2 of 5, Matrix 2 of 5, Trioptic Code, 
Stacked 1D: PDF417, Micro PDF417, Codablock A & F, Composite Codes
2D: Data Matrix, QR Code, Micro QR Code, Aztec Code, Maxicode

I am thinking of using PDF417. Does it have any disadvantages?

Comment: Eliminated UPC/EAN/JAN as they are numeric only and fixed length barcodes

Comment: All 2 of 5 codes can represent only 10 characters. So eliminated Interleaved 2 of 5, NEC 2 of 5, Matrix 2 of 5 Source

Comment: Eliminated code 39 because of its low data density Code 39. It requires more space to encode data in Code 39 than, for example, in Code 128.[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39)

Comment: Pdf417 will fit your requirements from 1 to 5

Comment: The width of a Code128 would depend on the data structure. It's relatively good at compressing numeric sequences. Not so good on alphas...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know all formats so I can't say which is best.

Some of the 1D barcodes you mention (UPC/EAN) support only a small number of numeric characters. I know Code 128 supports variable length alphanumeric values, so that probably is a good 1D candidate.

Some barcode readers don't support 2D barcodes, this is usually a reason to use 1D.

Of 2D you should see if there is a symbology that does not require the barcode to be a square, because that would limit your maximum size to 1.5 by 1.5 inches.

There are several websites that let you create barcodes as images - perhaps you should just create a PDF containing those and fax them to see what happens.

I don't know of any free libraries to render them with; there are also [fonts](http://www.dafont.com/code-128.font) out there that allow creating 1D barcodes, and you can [embed these fonts into your winforms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288246/how-can-i-bundle-a-font-with-my-net-winforms-application).

EDIT: 200 dpi on 8x1.5 inches would give you 1600 dots horizontally and 300 dots vertically to work with. A code128 barcode with a bar width of 1 pixel would come out at under 1400 dots.

On the [wikipedia page for QR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage) there is an example that takes up to 174 characters that has a size of 57x57 and high error correction. If I'm not mistaking, each dot could be represented by 5x5 pixels in 200dpi.

Comment: I have eliminated UPC,EAN from my list. Also I have eliminated code 39 as code 128 has better data density than code 39. But I would like to know the size of a 128 barcode that can encode 120 characters with 200dpi.<br/> The barcode reader will be decided only on the basis of the barcode which will be used in my application. <br/> Barcode fonts are used for creating low data density barcodes such as Code 39. So I need to find a good library in c# for barcode generation.

Comment: Updated my answer with dpi estimates, you'll have to verify them though, my calc.exe skills aren't that good.